# Explanation behind the reappearance of Eobard Thawne during Crisis on Earth X?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

[image: A still from Episode 1 of crossover Crisis On Earth X]Eobard Thawne's *sudden appearance* surprises me a lot, he dies, and then again reappears. But what's the specific explanation of him showing up during the **Crisis on Earth X** crossover? I remember him indirectly referring, being the *Reverse Flash of Earth 1* during the crossover, but what the heck is he doing on Earth X? And why's Tom Cavanagh playing Matt Letscher's role?

Comment: **Flashpoint** was the reason mate.. It changed many things

Comment: As far as I know **post-flashpoint**, Eobard Thawne was killed by the Black Flash in the Legend's of Tomorrow show's finale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the events in Flashpoint

From Wikia,

> An alternate timeline, coined Flashpoint by Eobard Thawne, was created
>   by Barry Allen when he traveled back in time and saved his mother from
>   the Reverse-Flash. The timeline was reset when the Reverse-Flash ran
>   back in time and killed Nora Allen again, restoring everything pretty
>   much to how it was before, albeit with some minor differences.
>   However, after Barry Allen used a superseding form of speedster time
>   travel to live in this timeline's version of 2016 for three months, he
>   found the world much different to the timeline that existed before,
>   with Cisco Ramon becoming the genius industrialist instead of Harrison
>   Wells and Tess Morgan, Wally West becoming The Flash instead of Barry,
>   and The Rival becoming a new menace of Central City
>
> *Legacy*
>
> The Flashpoint timeline can still be accessed by those with
>   dimensional awareness even though this timeline was reset by Eobard.
>   This was shown when Cisco vibed into Flashpoint to determine Clive
>   Yorkin's next victim. The victim was thought to resemble a cop in
>   Flashpoint.

**Changes between the Pre-Flashpoint and Post-Flashpoint timelines**

1. Joe West and Iris West became estranged for a time due to the
   revelation of her mother being alive.
2. Dante Ramon died in a car accident caused by a drunk driver. (This
   may have happened during those three months regardless of Barry's
   time traveling.)
3. Caitlin Snow developed meta-human powers exactly like those of her
   Earth Two counterpart, however this resulted in her developing a
   cold personality as well. (This may have happened during those three
   months regardless of Barry's time traveling: it's possible that
   Caitlin had gotten powers from the Particle Accelerator explosion in
   the pre-Flashpoint timeline too and they simply hadn't developed
   yet.)
4. S.T.A.R. Labs now has a speed lab where speedsters can train.
5. The members of Team Flash now have "panic buttons" installed on
   their phones.
6. John Diggle doesn't have a daughter anymore, but a son instead. In
   addition to the gender difference, Diggle's child was also born a
   month later in the new timeline.
7. Julian Albert started working at the CCPD as a CSI in late 2015. He
   also inadvertently released Savitar several years prior, and
   unknowingly became Alchemy as a result.
8. The future has changed, one specific change being Iris getting
   killed by Savitar in the future before the year 2024, with the
   future newspaper article instead being written by Julie Greer.
9. Ralph Dibny, who previously was one of the fourteen people who lost
   their lives in the particle accelerator explosion, is now alive.

*Additionally, the following events occur as a direct result of Flashpoint:*

1. Alchemy is able to restore the superhuman abilities of seven
   meta-humans who only had powers in the Flashpoint timeline: The
   Rival, Magenta, Shade, Clive Yorkin, Wally West, and two other
   unidentified people.
2. The Dominators launch an invasion of Earth, as they are alerted to
   Barry's time traveling and seek to prevent Earth's meta-humans from
   doing further damage to the universe.
3. The time remnant of Eobard Thawne (with memories of his 'future' as
   Harrison Wells) escapes to the present. He finds himself pursued by
   the Speed Force's ultimate enforcer, forcing him to stay for
   temporary amounts of time whenever he time travels. He attempts to
   further alter the timeline to change his fate, eventually leading to
   the creation of the Legion of Doom.

And of course, since things've changed, Thawne may not be dead as we thought he was. He is very much alive and seeking for revenge from barry

Answer (score -2):

Major spoilers for everyone, dear people. This will decently explain the whole mess on the Flash-LoT.

Short version:

Flashpoint Eobard becomes Wellsobard (without flawed Speed Force connection); when Eddie kills himself Eobard avoids erasure and goes in the Speed Force. He goes to 2000 and brings Barry back to 2016. Then Eobard goes to LoT; he is sent in the Speed Force by Black Flash. He escapes when Barry escapes from the Speed Force and appears on the Earth X crossover.

[image]